# Parsing Unicode Strings in LinkedIn JSON Responses using Scribe and FasterXML Jackson

Tags: unicode, jackson, linkedin-api, scribe

Hi I am developing a Java application using Scribe to integrate with Linkedin and make RestFul calls. I use FasterXML Jackson Json Parser library to parse the LinkedIn API responses in JSON.
I would like to check how I can parse Unicode characters in the response from LinkedIn when using the Jackson parser. When i do it the normal API call and print it out I see see ????? for those values that are returned in Unicode format.

Answer (score 1):

Unicode characters are handled by Jackson. But code that prints out content may not be using UTF-8 encoding; make sure you check out actual character codes and NOT rely on what you see on your console window. Console may be using incorrect encoding, for example, or not have fonts to display all Unicode characters.

Alternatively service may be sending incorrectly encoded content. To verify this, you must check out actual bytes sent and see if they are properly UTF-8 encoded.

Comment: hi staxman, thanks for the response. since most of the marshaling done under the hood how do i check if the received values are properly coded when using Jackson.

Comment: You can still check actual Unicode values of Java Strings; but ideally you should capture byte stream being processed.